# How to set column value by subtracting values from ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is snippset,

I want to set the value of balance column based on the entered Amt in Entered Amt column.

I tried this but in my scenarion, same vallue is setting for all balance column though i make change in only one column

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Amt" : "500",
      
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "800",
     
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1580",
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1122",
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.value=function(d)
  {
    //How set the value of balace amout by subtrating Amt-Entered Amt.
    //I tried this but in my scenarion, same vallue is setting for all balance column though i make change in only one column
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>Amt</td>
  <td>Balance</td> 
  <td>Entered Amt</td>  
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x.Amt}}</td>
  <td>{{balance}}</td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="d" ng-change="value(d)"></td>  
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the balance in your `x` object.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Amt" : "500",
      
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "800",
     
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1580",
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1122",
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.value=function(d, x)
  {
    //How set the value of balace amout by subtrating Amt-Entered Amt.
    //I tried this but in my scenarion, same vallue is setting for all balance column though i make change in only one column
    x.balance = x.Amt - d;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>Amt</td>
  <td>Balance</td> 
  <td>Entered Amt</td>  
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x.Amt}}</td>
  <td>{{x.balance}}</td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="d" ng-change="value(d, x)"></td>  
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated code
   HTML

```
        <div ng-app>
      <h2>Todo</h2>
      <div>
        <table ng-controller="TodoCtrl" border="1">
      <tr>
      <td>Amt</td>
      <td>Balance</td> 
      <td>Entered Amt</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,x) in records">
      <td>{{x.Amt}}</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly ng-model="balance[$index]"></td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="d" ng-change="value(x,d,$index)"></td>  
    </tr>
    </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    function myCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.balance = {};
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Amt" : "500",

    },
    {
      "Amt" : "800",

    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1580",
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1122",
    }
  ]

  $scope.value=function(obj,val,key)
  {

  $scope.balance[key] = parseInt(obj.Amt) - parseInt(val);
    //How set the value of balace amout by subtrating Amt-Entered Amt.
    //I tried this but in my scenarion, same vallue is setting for all balance column though i make change in only one column
  }
}
```